# AX200 Wi-Fi adapter working but update manager says the opposite

Tags: drivers, wireless, update-manager, iwlwifi

I am a complete Linux noob so be gentle.

I am dual booting (Windows 10, Ubuntu 20.04, wireless adapter intel AX200) for a week now and I have noticed a very strange thing:

When I am in Ubuntu OS, software update manager under additional drivers claims that the AX200 is not working. However, I have no problem whatsoever connecting wirelessly to my home network and bt also works like a charm.

I looked into `/lib/firmware`, and the corresponding firmware is there. Also, my system recognizes the adapter just fine. So maybe it is an update manager issue?

Do I leave it this way? How do I know that my adapter is working as intended and no action needs to be taken?

[image]

[image]